# Open InAppBrowser with Authorization Header

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, basic-authentication, angular2-http

For my Ionic2 app i have a requirement of downloading invoices but only for authenticated users. Is there any way to do it?

I have installed the InAppBrowser cordova plugin but it seems like it cannot be used for sending Authorization Header with request.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:
Look for the (YourProject)\plugins\cordova-plugin-inappbrowser\src\android\InAppBrowser.java file and edit it.

In the onReceivedHttpAuthRequest at the end of the file you should put something like this.

```
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {

        // Check if there is some plugin which can resolve this auth challenge
        String UserName = getUser();
        String Password = getPass();

        if (UserName != null && Password!= null) {
            handler.proceed(UserName, Password);
            return;
        }
```

You can replace the `getUser()` and `getPass()` with your username and password to try if is working, if it does. Create methods to retrieve the data from the inputs.

In my case I use this:

```
public void setUserPass(String username, String password) {
    this.USUARIO = username;
    this.CONTRASENA = password;
}    

public String getUser() {
    return this.USUARIO;
}

public String getPass() {
    return this.CONTRASENA;
}
```

Outside the method InAppBrowserClient that contains the onReceivedHttpAuthRequest method. Then almost in the top of the document I wrote this in the execute method (setUserPass(args.getString(3), args.getString(4));)

```
public boolean execute(String action, CordovaArgs args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals("open")) {
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
        final String url = args.getString(0);
        setUserPass(args.getString(3), args.getString(4));
        String t = args.optString(1);
        if (t == null || t.equals("") || t.equals(NULL)) {
            t = SELF;
        }
        final String target = t;
```

Then you have to edit the (YourProject)\plugins\cordova-plugin-inappbrowser\www\inappbrowser.js file at the end.

```
module.exports = function(strUrl, strWindowName, strWindowFeatures, callbacks) {
    // Don't catch calls that write to existing frames (e.g. named iframes).
    if (window.frames && window.frames[strWindowName]) {
        var origOpenFunc = modulemapper.getOriginalSymbol(window, 'open');
        return origOpenFunc.apply(window, arguments);
    }

    strUrl = urlutil.makeAbsolute(strUrl);
    var iab = new InAppBrowser();

    callbacks = callbacks || {};
    for (var callbackName in callbacks) {
        iab.addEventListener(callbackName, callbacks[callbackName]);
    }

    var cb = function(eventname) {
       iab._eventHandler(eventname);
    };

    strWindowFeatures = strWindowFeatures || "";

    exec(cb, cb, "InAppBrowser", "open", [strUrl, strWindowName, strWindowFeatures[0], strWindowFeatures[1], strWindowFeatures[2]]);
    return iab;
};
```

Finally, in the index.js or any js that control your app use the same call but you add your login data using the feature part as an array and like this:

window.open(url, '_blank', ['toolbar=no,presentationstyle=fullscreen,location=no,hardwareback=yes,hidden=no', username, password]);

To activate all this you should build the project in the console.

Hope this help somebody.