# Cordova Inappbrowser cannot display websites with authentication dialog (username and password)

Tags: javascript, authentication, inappbrowser

When the target of inappbrowsers is set to "_blank" it is not possible to show embedded website authentication dialog. This happens on android and iOS.

Cordova inappbrowser uses one of the three target parameters: "_blank", "_self" and "_system". 
When the target is set to "_blank" or "_self", website authentication dialog is blocked. This makes it impossible to use the login credentials (username and password).
With the target set to "_blank",  it is possible to use the event listeners and the embedded website runs as as expected. All test websites without authentication login work well.
When the target of the inappbowser is set to "_system", the authentication dialog is displayed. However, the authentication dialog and website open in the system browser. The website is not embedded in the app.  The app functionalities are useless in this case.

1. I have tried using the deeplink plugin as described in one of the inappbrowser issues on github: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/342
2. I modified the plugin as described: [Open InAppBrowser with Authorization Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041760/open-inappbrowser-with-authorization-header)

I expect the app to show the authentication dialog of the embedded website in the inappbrowser so that I can enter the username and password. Only a white screen is currently shown.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the plugin as described in [Open InAppBrowser with Authorization Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041760/open-inappbrowser-with-authorization-header) actually works. Don't forget to define your user and password variables in the InAppBrowser.java file.